# Tabcontrol on android

Tags: android

I want to make an Tab control on android.
But the tab control is displayed on top, wherein i want it to be displayed the bottom line

Can anybody help with that

Answer (score 1):

The tabwidget object in your layout is the view that will contain the tabs.
You can move it to whatever position you like on the screen.

This is an example on how to get it to the bottom of the screen with a RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      ...

      <TabWidget
         android:id="@android:id/tabs"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```